# Query vector tile server from geojson shape

Tags: request, geojson, bounding-box, vector-tiles

The idea is the following :

I have a **GeoJSON Polygon** and a ["vector tile"](https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-spec) endpoint. I'd like to query the vector tile server to get relevant features filtered within the bounding box of the Polygon. (The final objective is to compute data and find out if some data intersects my Polygon, but for now let's stick to "features in the area of the polygon")

Explained differently I'd like to do the following :

- Find the bbox of the polygon
- Find the "bounds" of relevant tiles
- Query the tile server with that bounds
- Parse the received features

As a very noob in vector tile spec, I'm struggling with the 2 middle parts.

- [I know how to find the bbox](http://turfjs.org/docs#bbox)
- *How to "expand" that bbox and convert it to vector tiles coordinates ?*

  I think it's there, somewhere in Mapbox tools, but I can't find it
- *How to "query a VT endpoint with bounds" ?*

  VT endpoints requests (taken from mapboxGL) tend to look like this
  `https://tile-server.com/15/16665/11033.pbf`, which i roughly understand as `/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf`, but the encoding of `x` and `y` looks strange
- [I theorically know how to decode received .pbf to GeoJSON](https://github.com/mapbox/geobuf#decode)

---

Nota Bene : I'm achieving this **server-side** therefore I can't use any graphical webGl related stuff from MapboxGL

---

BONUS: ad the end of story, event if I manage to convert polygon's bbox to vector tiles coordinates, I'll need a zoom to query the server. I don't want it to be arbitrary, so another question : *how to find the "best zoom" for a polygon ?*

Comment: Maybe you can put your data in PostGIS and use it's powerful function (incuding direct MVT-support). In addition you can use postgis-vt-util (https://github.com/mapbox/postgis-vt-util)